# Return the 2D array as a list, but print as a generator object

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I wrote a function that creates a matrix based on the values entered. However, despite the function returning a list, its output is displayed as generator objects. What's the reason for this situation and how do I print the function output as a list? Thanks!

```
import random
def gnrtRandomMtrcs(row, column):
    lowercase = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    uppercase = list("ABCDEFGJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ")
    numbercase = list("0123456789")
    random.shuffle(lowercase)
    random.shuffle(uppercase)
    random.shuffle(numbercase)
    allcases = []
    allcases.append(item for item in lowercase)
    allcases.append(item for item in uppercase)
    allcases.append(item for item in numbercase)
    random.shuffle(allcases)
    matrices = [[i * j for j in range(column)] for i in range(row)]
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(column):
            matrices[i][j] = random.choice(allcases)
    return matrices
```

The sample output when the parameters are 3 and 2:

```
[[<generator object gnrtRandomMtrcs.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0337E4F8>,
  <generator object gnrtRandomMtrcs.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0337E4F8>], 
 [<generator object gnrtRandomMtrcs.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0337E4F8>, 
  <generator object gnrtRandomMtrcs.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0337E568>], 
 [<generator object gnrtRandomMtrcs.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0337E4F8>, 
  <generator object gnrtRandomMtrcs.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0337E4F8>]]
```

But I want the output to be this way:

```
[['L', '0'],['2', '6'],['b', 'K']]
```

**Edited:** The problem was solved when the for loop was written in a long way and not in a single line. But I didn't understand why because I think both of them mean the same situation.

In these lines:

```
allcases.append(item for item in lowercase)
allcases.append(item for item in uppercase)
allcases.append(item for item in numbercase)
```

I made these corrections:

```
for item in lowercase:
    allcases.append(item)
for item in uppercase:
    allcases.append(item)
for item in numbercase:
    allcases.append(item)
```

And finally it came out just like I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In these lines:

```
    allcases.append(item for item in lowercase)
    allcases.append(item for item in uppercase)
    allcases.append(item for item in numbercase)
```

You appear to be appending a generator expression. Try placing brackets inside the parenthesis.

```
    allcases.append([item for item in lowercase])
```

Comment: If we do as you say, before: [['u', 'c',..., 'p', 'g']] then: [['u', 'c',..., 'p', 'g'], ['S', 'X', ..., 'U', 'Z']] and we see steps that go this way, but I want all additions to be the same list element. like this:['u', 'c',...,'3', '5']

Comment: @DenizCanTufekci The simplest version would be ```allcases.extend([lowercase])``` - lowercase is a list, and extend glues one list onto another (doesn't make a nested list like append would).